# Linux не запускается.Битые блоки(Bad Blocks),суперблоки(Super Blocks).Замена microSD карты./dev/mmcblk0p1: unexpected incomsistency; Run fsck manually

Tags: linux, orange-pi

*Orange Pi; Armbian(ОС для однопалатных компьютеров на базе ARM - процессоров); microSD card;*

Сначала перестал входить в phpmyadmin по удалёнке, потом в консоли началась какая-то ерунда, я сделал reboot и система перестала загружаться.
Вставил microSD в компьютер, раздел монтируется, все файлы на месте.

В интернете нашёл варианты с fsck, не помогло, так же нашел резервные супер блоки и попытался их заменить, не помогло. Пишет, что файловая система еще содержит ошибки. Изначально хотел зайти через chroot, но не поддерживается, да и не знаю поможет ли это.

**Вопрос:** возможно ли, восстановить систему? 
Поскольку на ней mysql, phpmyadmin с настройками и другие пакеты, различные настройки: ssh, UART, fstab, автозапуска. 
У меня есть еще одна новая microSD карта, может возможно перенести систему или же хотя бы перенести БД и настройки пакетов? [image: Фото ошибки]

Comment: fsck на компьютере делали? «Все файлы на месте» ничего не значит, если вы не пытались эти файлы прочитать. Если файлы всё же читаются, то, пока карточка не развалилась окончательно, можно попробовать сделать на компьютере бэкап с помощью например каким-нибудь `tar --acls --xattrs -cvf /path/to/backup.tar /path/to/microsd` (команда примерная) (хотя вообще-то бэкапы нужно было делать заранее)

Comment: выглядит так буд-то карта [полу]мёртвая... пробовал через `dd`/`ddrescue` на другую перегнать всё?

Comment: Всё! Система запустилась! С помощью ddrescue снял образ, сначала без битых блоков, а потом продолжил дополнять его считывая битые блоки с повтором 3 раза. Спустя 16 часов образ был готов. Залил на новую карту и всё запустилось. Сейчас делаю проверки с fsck и после сохраню новый бэкап.

Comment: Только вопрос, а как делать бэкап работающей системы? К примеру у меня есть микрокомпьютер с системой, который работает 24/7.

Comment: @BladzheR, хорошим тоном будет дать ответ с подробной инструкцией для тех, кто в будущем напорется на нечто подобное... по поводу бекапа — тема большая и сильно зависит от деталей системы... для контроллеров обычной практикой является бекап начального состояния при заливке прошивки. Для «больших контроллеров»/«маленьких серверов» также возможны бекапы отдельных частей, например базы данных, со своими методами... ЗЫ: обычно на вопросы в комментариях ни кто не отвечает, окромя OP'а... особенно если нет упоминания, кому конкретно он адресован..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решение данной ситуации:**

Вставил карту памяти в компьютер.
Далее сделал копию в образ(.img) с помощью ddrescue, сначала с параметром *--no-split* (без "проблемных" секторов)

```
ddrescue --no-split /dev/sde imagefile.img logfile.log
```

Ушло минут 15.
Далее выполнил:

```
modprobe raw
raw /dev/raw/raw1 /dev/sde
ddrescue --max-retries=3 --complete-only /dev/raw/raw1 imagefile.img logfile.log
```

**Если ругается** на *--max-retries=3*, я заменил на *--retry-passes=3*

Ушло часов 16 на выполнение данной команды.

*Далее выполнил:*

```
raw /dev/raw/raw1 0 0
```

Подключил новую карту памяти(объем карты должен быть не меньше старой карты, у меня была на 16GB, я поставил на 32GB)

*Восстанавливаем из образа:*

```
ddrescue -f image.img /dev/sda1 logfile.log
```

*Запустил с новой карты, всё запустилось. 
Сразу выполнил:*

```
tune2fs -c 1 /dev/mmcblk0o1
reboot
```

Убедился, что проверка файловой системы прошла.Проверил работу всех пакетов.
С помощью *gparted* расширил раздел с 16GB до 32GB.
Сделал бэкап, так же с помощью *ddrescue*.

**Готово!**

**Полезные ссылки:**

[altlinux.org/Восстановление_данных_со_сбойного_накопителя_и_копирование_в_образ](https://www.altlinux.org/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7)

[устранения проблем файловых систем](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/file-sys/4-tools-for-filesystem-health.html)

[Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123963/how-to-force-fsck-at-every-boot-all-relevant-filesystems)

Comment: Не могли бы вы изменить вопрос? (переименовать его на что-нибудь такое, что связано с ошибкой, и почему не запускается), может кто будет гуглить по ошибке, и не найдёт вашего вопроса/ответа, который, очевидно, смог бы помочь кому-то)